# How to store (and/or POST) user ID as their form is POSTed?

Tags: php, session

I'm building a site where users create profiles and projects (startups, research, inventions, etc) and share and connect with others for a valuable exchange.

I started the site sometime ago with a friend and we've since stopped working on it together.  He wrote all of the php and I did all the front end.  Now I'm doing both and the concept has changed a bit.  This means I'm adapting a lot of the code he has already written.

When users posts a new project, there is certain background information that needs to be posted with it.  Therefore, when they create a new post I want to store their ID with it.  This way when their post is displayed, it also shows the pertinent user profile information.

How do I properly store (and/or POST) their user ID as the form is POSTed?

(I apologize, I'm fairly new to PHP.  Doing my best with the lingo.)

Here is some of the code (not all is needed, I know)

```
<?php
require_once("../includes/config.php");
require_once("../assets/classes/projects.php");
$x = new projects();

if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1;
}

$dbh = config::get();

$checkCountQ = $dbh->prepare("SELECT cork_user_notes.tf_index FROM `cork_user_notes` INNER JOIN `cork_users` ON cork_user_notes.tf_index = cork_users.tf_index WHERE cork_users.tf_username = :un");
$checkCountQ->bindParam(":un", $_GET['user']);
$checkCountQ->execute();
$checkCountR = $checkCountQ->rowCount();

?>

<form action="addProjects.php" method="POST">

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Enter your project name
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="project name">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                     Enter your project's category
                </td>
                <td>    
                    <select name="category">
                         <option value="1">Startup</option>
                         <option value="2">Software</option>
                         <option value="3">Hardware</option>
                         <option value="4">Research</option>
                         <option value="5">Discovery</option>
                         <option value="6">Invention</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: where do you have the user id ? in session?

Comment: @sgt I do believe so.  Perhaps I'm already storing it, and just need to pull it properly?

Answer (score 0):

Allowing the user to alter their `user_id` is not safe for your records because a user could pose as someone else. Here there is no `user_id` in your code, only their `username` which if unique, might work just as well. In order to do this efficiently it might be best to pass the value in a hidden form field in addition to a hashed field that contains a value known only to you to verify on the other side:

```
<?php
print "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"uid\" value=\"".$_SESSION['username']."\">"; 
print "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"uidh\"
value=\"".md5($_SESSION['username']."Something that only you know")."\">";
?>
```

On the other side you check the hash.

```
if (!empty($_POST['uid'])&&!empty($_POST['uidh'])
      &&$_POST['uid']==md5($_POST['uidh']."Something that only you know")){
//then they're okay
} else {
//fail spectacularly at their attempt
}
```

If your server is setup to handle sessions with cookies, the cookies are unsafe and can't be trusted as well.

To verify sessions you would want to hash the data with a unique key only known to you as well.

Comment: I probably explained my intents poorly.  I don't want to have the user add their own ID.  I want to store the user ID with the form or content.
Does that make sense?  I'm probably making it sound more complicated than it is.

Answer (score 0):

Why does the user ID value need to be posted from the form at all?

You have an authenticated user, you have their user's ID on the server side in some shape or fashion (maybe stored in the session or something similar). Use that when creating the project, and do **not** accept a user-supplied user ID.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I don't want to ask them.  I just want to pass the user ID with the rest of the form.

I'm pretty sure it's any easy thing and I'm just making it difficult.

Comment: Don't do it. It's a big security risk - your users can just change it to be any ID they like. You'd have to have the user ID on the server side to put it into the form anyway - just populate it on the server side on form submission instead.

Comment: That's certainly what I want to do^.  I certainly don't want to have the user populate it him/herself.
How do I pass that to the database when the form is POSTed?

Answer (score -1):

Two ways to do this.

1. You session the user id when the user logs in like this

   ```
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $id;
   ```

which you can subsequently used anywhere in the website as this case maybe when inserting

2. create an hidden field in the form to store userid

   ```
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['userid']; ?>" />
   ```

you can then get it with `$_POST['id']` when submit button isset.

Comment: no - users can tamper with forms and change hidden values. Don't do this.